# Can you do logistic regression in R on a full dataset rather than the training data (i.e. 80%) of the dataset?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic, model-evaluation

Using a logistic regression model to predict something in my dataset but was just wondering do I need to split the full dataset into training data (i.e. 80%) and test data (i.e. 20%) to make a model or can it be done with the use of the full dataset?

I have created a model using glm with the full dataset at present but just wondering if this is one way to do logistic regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Prediction is only one of the possible goals of logistic regression. It can also be used for statistical inference e.g. doing statistical tests on the coefficients of the Maximum Likelihood Estimation. However, if you use your model for prediction, then it is important to keep your training and test set seperate to avoid Data Leakage i.e. having overly confident estimates of prediction accuracy because the model was evaluated on the same data it was trained on.